# Hibernate: Entity xx with id xx not found, one to one relationship

Tags: database, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use Hibernate for the first time, so I am not very familiar with the syntax yet. I am trying to model a library system. The classes that are causing problem are "Borrow" and "CopyBook" which are as following:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "copybook", schema="project")
public class CopyBook {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="copy_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int copyId;

    @Convert(converter = StatusAttributeConverter.class)
    @Column(name="status", columnDefinition = "TEXT DEFAULT 'AVAILABLE'")
    private Status status;


    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book book;

    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "copy")
    private Borrow borrow;

    public Borrow getBorrow() {
        return borrow;
    }

    public void setBorrow(Borrow borrow) {
        this.borrow = borrow;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "copy", optional = false)
    private Order order;

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "borrow", schema = "project")
public class Borrow {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="no_borrow", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int noBorrow;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="date_borrow", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Date dateBorrow;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="date_return")
    private Date dateReturn;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="max_date_return", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date maxDateReturn;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "copy_id")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private CopyBook copy;

    public CopyBook getCopy() {
        return copy;
    }

    public void setCopy(CopyBook copy) {
        this.copy = copy;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="mem_id")
    private Members member;

    public Members getMember() {
        return member;
    }

    public void setMember(Members member) {
        this.member = member;
    }
}
```

I am using IntelliJ, so when I try to run the query of the Borrow entity it showed me that it cannot find `CopyBook` with id 1 even though it actually exists in the database

[image]

This is the entries currently present in my database (In these two table)

CopyBook:

[image: CopyBook]

Borrow:

[image]

As we can see, there is indeed a `CopyBook` with id of 1. This is also proved when I run the query of `CopyBook` entity which successfully returned all the results

Result after running in JPA `select entity from CopyBook entity`

[image]

Just to see what results `Borrow` is actually giving, I have added `@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)`. And this is the result I get

[image]

So I found this is a very bizarre situation because all data exist, and `CopyBook` is able to find its correspondent `Borrow`. But `Borrow` is unable to find its correspondent `CopyBook` ?

Strangley, I have another entity class `Order` which has almost the same attributes (Also has a OneToOne relationship with `CopyBook`), and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

Because I have multiple One-To-Many relationship, and the `FetchType` is by default `Eager`. Whenever I want to retrieve the entity, it will perform Left Outer Join for all the entities until the end.

However, under the scope of this context. A book does not have to be ordered to exist in the library, be performing "JOIN" it loses entries and therefore causes the aforementioned problem.

As a result, all I did was to set the attributes`Order` and `Borrow` with `optional = true` and `fetch = Fetchtype.Lazy` so it will not perform join unless necessary